# AttributeError in views.py: type object 'Transaction' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I have run into an issue using Django. I am creating a finance app which tracks deposits and withdrawals.Unfourtanently I have run into an issue using models. Here is the relevant code

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Transaction

# Create your views here.
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, name, description, location, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.location = location
        self.amount = amount    

def sum(totals):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(totals)):
        if totals[i].name.lower() == 'deposit':
            sum += totals[i].amount
        else:
            sum -= totals[i].amount
    return sum


#transactions = [
#   Transaction('Deposit', 'Allowance', 'Home', 25.00),
#   Transaction('Withdrawl', 'Food', 'Bar Burrito', 11.90),
#   Transaction('Withdrawl', 'Snacks', 'Dollarama', 5.71)
#]



def index(request):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    balance = sum(transactions)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'transactions':transactions,  'balance': balance})
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Transaction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Transaction

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Transaction)
```

Let me know if there is any other code you need to look at and thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a second `Transaction` class in your views. It is shadowing the `Transaction` model/class imported from your model. **Remove** it!

More so, you also don't need a custom *sum* function, use the builtin **`sum`**:

```
def index(request):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    balance = sum(t.amount if t.name=='deposit' else -t.amount for t in transactions)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Transaction` class that you have in your `views.py` file shadows your `Transaction` model.

`Transaction` in `views.py` file is a simple python class (not a Django model), to fix your issue, you need to remove it from `views.py`